# Tic-Tac-Toe in Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can tic tac toe be completed (5 1s and 4 0s) so that rank(A)=2, but neither side passed up a winning move?
This is question 39 of an Exercise in Gilbert Strang's text on Linear algebra.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every tic tac toe game that ends in a tie with $5$ $1$s and $4$ $0$s can have its rows/columns permuted to bring it into the form
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&1}
$$
Note that permuting rows and columns does *not* change the rank of a matrix.

Comment: This means that every game that ends in a tie must have rank =3, right?

Comment: If “winning move” only means “a move that immediately wins,” doesn’t this work and have rank $2$? $\pmatrix{1_1&1_3&0_2\\0_1&0_3&1_4\\1_2&1_4&0_4}$

Comment: @SteveKass good catch, I guess I was wrong

Comment: @doubts_94 My answer is incorrect